How can I disable Delphi 11.3 from autohiding the compiler dialog after it finished?
In Delphi 11.3, when I press Ctrl+F9 to compile my project,  when the compiler finishes compiling, then it automatically closes the compile dialog.
I don't want the dialog to automatically close when compiling has finished.
How can I disable this feature?

I found the checkbox on the compiler dialog to disable the close on successful compile!

Simply make sure that the checkbox is unticked while it's busy compiling and then it won't automatically close the compile dialog when compiling is finished.
